# Get unicode string out of binary data in python

Tags: python, networking, unicode, decoding

I have some UCF-2 data in a normal string received from a server. How can I get a unicode() string out of this?

EG:
`>>> something('\0a\0b\0c')` = `u'abc'`

Comment: I think he means "UCS-2", but needs confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> '\0a\0b\0c'.decode('UTF-16BE')
u'abc'
```